# Limit number of selected items in RadListView

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, nativescript, mobile-development

The [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/selection) for the RadListView in nativescript says that the `itemSelecting` event "Can be used to cancel the operation". How would such behavior be implemented? I am trying to limit the amount of items selected through this method. I already have implemented the event method and have tried simply deselecting the item but this doesn't work and I feel is very inefficient anyway.

```
onItemSelecting({ index, object }) {
    if (object.getSelectedItems().length >= maxSelectedItems) {
        object.deselectItemAt(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `returnValue` to `false` in order to prevent the selection

```
onItemSelecting(event) {
    if (event.object.getSelectedItems().length >= maxSelectedItems) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost works. If you click on the same item twice in the RadListView it gets selected anyway.

Comment: It seems that the itemSelecting event does not get fired again.

Comment: Please share a Playground sample of the issue.

Comment: I made an issue on the GitHub, it has been passed onto the correct people.